# Create simple input component failed

Tags: html, angular

I've try to create an input component, which handles some logic and stop copy and pasting HTML code.

Therefor I've added an `input.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    selector: 'input-component',
    templateUrl: 'input.component.html'
})

export class InputComponent {
  @Input()
  public type;

  @Input()
  public id;

  @Input()
  public label;

  @Input()
  public formControlName;

  @Input()
  public cssClasses;

  @Input()
  public withErrors = false;

  @Input()
  public error;

  @Input()
  public controls;

  public isFocused: boolean;
}
```

The template for this component is this `input.component.html`:

```
<input id="{{ id }}"
   class="{{ cssClasses }}"
   type="{{ type }}"
   [ngClass]="{
            'has-error': error && !isFocused,
            'not-empty': controls.value && controls.value.length > 0
            }"
   spellcheck=false
   (focus)="isFocused = true"
   (blur)="isFocused = false">
<label for="{{ id }}" [ngClass]="{'has-error': error && !isFocused}">{{ label }}</label>
<div id="formErrors-{{ id }}" *ngIf="error && !isFocused && withErrors" class="alert help-block with-errors">
    {{ error }}
</div>
```

Is this even possible, or otherwise, if not, is there a proper reason to stop thinking about it?

Would be great if I can call the InputComponent this way:

```
     <input-component
    [type]="'text'"
    [id]="'streetName'"
    [label]="'Street'"
    [formControl]="'street'"
    [cssClasses]="'form-control width-100'"
    [withErrors]="true"
    [error]="formErrors['street']"
    [controls]="addressDataForm.controls['street']"></input-component>
```

I've created this but until now I always get the following error:

`Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute
Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name attribute`

The DOM looks like the properties from the `input.component.ts` are not rendered in the template:

```
<input-component ng-reflect-type="text" ng-reflect-id="streetName" ng-reflect-label="Street"
             ng-reflect-css-classes="form-control width-100" ng-reflect-with-errors="true" ng-reflect-error=""
             ng-reflect-controls="[object Object]">
    <input spellcheck="false">
    <label></label>
    <!---->
</input-component>
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Should be `[type]="'text'"`, not `[type="'text'"`. You just misspelled

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Great! This helps. But now its seems like the properties from the input component, not been rendered in the template...

Comment: Only in template? Can you log them in input component? Do they have a value?

Comment: @CommercialSuicide Yeah.. Only in the template, if I write an ```ngOnInit``` inside the input.component.ts the properties are logged correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Error: No value accessor for form control with unspecified name
>   attribute

You should specify `ngDefaultControl` attribute for your custom component, like this:

```
<input-component
    [type]="'text'"
    [id]="'streetName'"
    [label]="'Street'"
    [formControl]="'street'"
    [cssClasses]="'form-control width-100'"
    [withErrors]="true"
    [error]="formErrors['street']"
    [controls]="addressDataForm.controls['street']"
    ngDefaultControl>
</input-component>
```

> TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'street'

Change `[formControl]="'street'"` attribute of `input-component` to `[formControlName]="'street'"`.

It should solve the issue.

Comment: Thanks. This ```ngDefaultControl``` solve the issue. But the data from the parent template, which are in the component, are still missing in the template.

Comment: ```TypeError: Cannot create property 'validator' on string 'street'```

Comment: @Vico, nice to hear that